# AVSpeechSynthesizer and memory leaks in Xcode Instruments

Tags: memory-leaks, xcode-instruments, avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

Every time I use speech synthesizer, Instruments reports memory leaks. Hiding system libraries in the Call Tree section leaves no entries in the call tree display. I understand that the leaks are caused by some system call. Or am I missing something? Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?